# Does STLLoader accepts a web URL and display the file?

Tags: angular, three.js, stl-format

I want to render or load a .stl file from the web (https://cdn.thingiverse.com/assets/99/39/31/f9/33/90_Degree_-_4_Segments.stl) with the help of STLLoader. I am doing this stuff in Angular.

```
var loader=new STLLoader();
```

Can I place the web url link in the loader.load ? The web url link is taken as an input from the user.

```
   loader.load('https://cdn.thingiverse.com/assets/99/39/31/f9/33/90_Degree_-_4_Segments.stl',geometry =>{
     var material = new MeshPhongMaterial( { color: this.col });
     var mesh = new Mesh( geometry, material );
     this.scene.add(mesh);

   })
```

Could anyone suggest any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You can't load this asset from the given URL because of the CORS policy. Meaning the backend does not add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the HTTP response. Hence, it's not possible to load it with an AJAX request.

You have to ensure to serve the asset in a way so `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is set.

BTW: Here is a live example that demonstrates the error (open the browser console to see the message): https://jsfiddle.net/em8upjdz/

Comment: So I need to always provide the local path in the loader and never an URL correct?

Comment: This would definitely work. But you can also serve with a different host as long as you provide CORS headers.